# Sublime Text ReactJS autocomplete Attributes

Tags: reactjs, sublimetext3

Is there a way to get autocomplete to work with JSX attributes the same way autocomplete works with HTML files. For example, In HTML if I have a  tag and start typing onclick than the autocomplete window shows (See Image Bellow). I can't seem to get this to work with JSX. I am using Babel and Emmet packages. Emmet autocompletes the tags, but no attribute autocompletion. Is there an option I need to enable?

[image]

Comment: Attribute completions in core Sublime come from a plugin in the `HTML` package (specifically `HTML/html_completions.py`). There's no setting to modify the list of completions, so you would need a third party package or plugin, or modify the core plugin.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the let me know how it works. I'll look around and see if I can find a sublime package that can do this.Thanks!